# Is the countable complement topology connected if the set is infinite

Tags: general-topology

There are two cases, I need to work on. If X is countably infinite and uncountably infinite. The second case is easy to show its connected by contradiction. If the topology is connected, then there are two sets A and B both closed whose union is X. But that is impossible because X is uncountable and all closed sets are countable. Hence the set is connected for uncountable case.

Now I need to work on the countably infinite case and I'm stuck on this one. I'm not sure whether this is also connected or not.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is countable with countable complement topology then every point is open, since its complement is countable. Therefore $X$ is discrete and so disconnected as every discrete space with at least $2$ points is.